# How to make GCC optimize passing and returning structs by value better?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, struct, pass-by-value

I am writing a 3d vector math library for use on an embedded system with constrained memory. Most C math libraries use the "output parameter" idiom, which I strongly dislike. After hearing people like Chandler Carruth talk about how compilers are very good at optimizing pass- and return-by-value, I became faithful that it was a viable choice for working with structs of 3 floats. (In my use case, all functions are inlined in the header file, so preserving the calling convention should not matter.)

However, after writing my library and using it for its intended application, I find that the stack usage is very high. I can save many bytes of stack space by switching back to an old "output parameter" style, or even worse, in-place modification.

This sample code demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct vec {
    float x; float y; float z;
} vec;

inline float vdot(vec a, vec b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}

inline float vdotp(vec const *a, vec const *b) {
    return a->x * b->x + a->y * b->y + a->z * b->z;
}

inline vec vscale(float s, vec a) {
    vec v = { .x = s * a.x, .y = s * a.y, .z = s * a.z };
    return v;
}

inline void vscalep(float s, vec *a) {
    a->x = s * a->x;
    a->y = s * a->y;
    a->z = s * a->z;
}

inline vec vnormalize(vec a) {
    float s = 1.0f / sqrtf(vdot(a, a));
    return vscale(s, a);
}

inline void vnormalizep(vec *a) {
    float s = 1.0f / sqrtf(vdotp(a, a));
    vscalep(s, a);
}

inline vec vproject(vec a, vec b) {
    vec bnorm = vnormalize(b);
    float s = vdot(a, bnorm);
    return vscale(s, bnorm);
}

inline void vprojectp(vec *a, vec const *b) {
    vec bnorm = *b;
    vnormalizep(&bnorm);
    float s = vdotp(a, &bnorm);
    vscalep(s, &bnorm);
    *a = bnorm;
}

int main() {
    vec a = { .x = rand(), .y = rand(), .z = rand() };  
    vec b = { .x = rand(), .y = rand(), .z = rand() };  
#ifdef PTRS
    vprojectp(&a, &b);
#else
    a = vproject(a, b);
#endif
    printf("a: %f, %f, %f\n", a.x, a.y, a.z);
}
```

I would hope that, with all the functions in the same file and marked `inline`, the compiler would be able to "destructure" my pass-by-value code into its core scalar math operations, and produce roughly the same stack size for both versions. However, it cannot:

```
> gcc -O3 -fconserve-stack -Wstack-usage=30 main.c -lm

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:52:6: warning: stack usage is 64 bytes [-Wstack-usage=]
```

whereas with the in-place version:

```
> gcc -O3 -fconserve-stack -Wstack-usage=30 -DPTRS main.c -lm

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:52:6: warning: stack usage is 48 bytes [-Wstack-usage=]
```

In my real application, I see this same problem on a much larger scale. Passing by value is costing me hundreds of bytes in stack space.

Is there any way to get better stack usage optimization in this scenario? I am already using `fconserve-stack`. I am willing to spend any amount of extra optimization time to get better results.

(I am using GCC 4.9 for ARM, but the same problem happens on x86-64. The stack sizes from my sample code are for x86-64.)

Comment: Cough, cough. C++ `const vec &param`.

Comment: Yeah I would vastly prefer to be using C++ for this project, mainly because of operator overloading.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you change all occurrences of `inline` to `static`  ?  (in gnu89, `inline` functions without `static` are externally visible, so the compiler will be restricted in what optimizations it can perform)

Comment: On GCC 4.7, I get the same results with and without `-DPTRS`.  Try `-fwhole-program` — when I enable this, I get 80 bytes for main (and no other warnings) whether or not PTRS is enabled.

Comment: @Kaz doesn't really address the problem, it's just syntactic sugar. In theory it'd be nice if a compiler could optimize the pass-by-value version instead of requiring us to do the hack of passing by const-reference as a hand-optimization.

Comment: M.M. Fact is, this syntactic sugar lets you turn the by-value version into the by-reference, without changing its body, just by changing the declaration. Thus you don't have to care. In C++ you just habitually pass everything that is aggregate as `const &` and be done with it.

Comment: What does the generated assembly look like?